# Pagination on array stored in a field - Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a document with the following format:

```
{
  "email": "john.doe@gmail.com",
  "first_name": "John",
  "last_name": "Doe",
  "items": [
    {
      "id": 140,
      "description": ...,
    },
    {
      "id": 156",
      "description": ...,
    },
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to get a paginate list of the "items" field using scroll pagination and I tried with something similar to the following query:

```
http://localhost:9200/my_index/users/_search?scroll=1m

{   
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
      "ids": {
          "type": "users",
          "values": [
              "00000001"
          ]
      }
  },
  "_source": "items"
}
```

But it is paginating the users and not the items, and I don't know if there is a way to paginate the elements of a given field, instead the elements of the document itself.

I'm using Elasticsearch 2.3.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use nested object instead of array of object in Elasticsearch.

> Arrays of objects do not work as you would expect: you cannot query each object independently of the other objects in the array. If you need to be able to do this then you should use the nested data type instead of the object data type.

For more information check Elasticsearch official documentation about arrays [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/array.html) and for Nested object [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html).

After changing your mapping to nested object you will be able to query like this:

**Query**

```
GET my-index-000001/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "items",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            { "match": { "items.id": "ids" }}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Also ES 2.x is really old and different type are not supported anymore in Elasticsearch you might want to update your Elasticsearch as well.